# AWS - PUTTY "No supported authentication methods available (server sent :publickey)" After change instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, putty

I got the classical problem *"No supported authentication methods available (server sent :publickey)"* after that I changed the instance type (from *t2.micro* to *t2.xlarge*). I setted Putty up with the new parameters: I inserted the new IP after stop and re-lunch the instance, and the username of my machine remain being the same [*ubuntu* or *root*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21535907/disconnected-no-supported-authentication-methods-available-server-sent-publi). When I setted *root* like user in Putty, this throw me *"Please login as the user "ubuntu" rather than the user "root"".*

I don't know possible solutions, I was thinking to create a new *Key pair name*, because the  Key that is currently in Putty was created before to change my instance from *t2.micro* to *t2.xlarge*. I have not tried already because I don't want to messed up more the process.

Further, I have installed RStudio Server in my EC2 and I can realize that the *ubuntu* user is working, so I think that the unique option to solve this problem is changing the *Key pair name* because when you change it [you should to set up you user name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881469/change-key-pair-for-ec2-instance).

Have you had the same problem? How to resolve it? Is changing the *Key Pair Name*?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What were the steps you performed to change your instance?  Did you stop the t2.micro instance (without terminating it), change the type to t2.xlarge, and start the instance again?  Or did you terminate the t2.micro instance and launch a new t2.xlarge instance to replace it?

Comment: Changing instance size has never altered the login details for any instance I use. Log in using the ubuntu user and the private key from the key pair associated with the instance. If you've lost the private key you'll have to create a new key pair, a new instance, and mount the volume as a data volume to retrieve data.